# How to Upgrade Sony Xperia Z3 Compact (D5803) to Android 8.1?

Tags: updates, bootloader, 8.1-oreo, sony-xperia-z3

How do you upgrade the [Sony Xperia Z3 Compact (D5803)](https://support.sonymobile.com/ca-en/xperiaz3compact/supportDocumentation/) to Android 8.1?

There are a number of web pages that attempt to answer this question, but none of them provide every step along the way. These include:

- https://forum.xda-developers.com/z3-compact/general/z3-compact-marshmallow-to-oreo-step-step-t3720857
- https://www.getdroidtips.com/omnirom-xperia-z3-compact-8-1-oreo/
- https://rootmygalaxy.net/install-android-8-1-oreo-on-sony-xperia-z3-with-carbonrom-cr-6-1/
- https://arnowelzel.de/en/carbonrom-on-the-sony-xperia-z3-compact
- https://www.kbloghub.com/2018/02/root-install-twrp-recovery-on-sony-xperia-z3-compact.html
- https://www.reddit.com/r/SonyXperia/comments/5vt6cs/flashing_marshmallow_concept_rom_on_a_sony_xperia/

They all skip steps or are missing key pieces of information that someone who is unfamiliar with the process would prevent from completing. A comprehensive, step-by-step guide for a complete novice would be helpful.

Comment: Disclaimer: unlocking the bootloader will lose some Sony proprietary DRM protected functionality, such as X-Reality Engine and Miracast. And there's no way to get it back if it's gone, unless you make a backup of a specific partition. More details here: https://www.xda-developers.com/restore-lost-functionality-unlocked-xperia/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Upgrade Sony Xperia Z3 Compact to Android 8.1

These instructions describe how to upgrade the Sony Xperia Z3 Compact (D5803) smart phone. These instructions do not include backup instructions, so be sure to save any important information and then proceed at your own risk.

### Requirements

- Laptop or Desktop - Windows 7
- Xperia - Stock Build Number 23.5.A.1.291 ([revert](http://www.xperiablog.net/2016/03/12/install-xperia-marshmallow-using-flashtool-and-xperifirm-guide/) if necessary)
- Xperia - Fully charged (100% recommended)
- [Xperia Companion](https://www.sony.ca/en/electronics/support/articles/00236877)
- TWRP

### Disclaimer

These instructions could brick your phone, rendering it a paperweight. *Read all the instructions thoroughly at least once **before you begin.***

Unlocking the bootloader erases Sony's DRM-protected functionality, such as X-Reality Engine and Miracast. Unless you make a backup of a specific partition, the functionality will be permanently lost.

### Enable Developer Mode

Enable developer mode on the phone as follows:

1. Power on the phone
2. Open **Settings**
3. Tap **About phone**
4. Scroll down to **Build number**
5. Tap **Build number** at least 7 times in succession
6. Enable developer mode

Developer mode is enabled.

### Install Device Drivers

On the laptop or desktop computer, perform the following steps:

1. Disconnect Phone from USB, if not already disconnected
2. Download [Flashtool](http://www.flashtool.net/downloads.php) v0.9.24.4 for Windows

   - Hint: Use [BitPort.io](https://bitport.io/) and a [throw away email](https://www.mailinator.com/) service to download torrent (fast download)
3. Install into `C:\Flashtool`
4. Plug phone into laptop or desktop USB port
5. Run `C:\Flashtool\drivers\Flashtool-drivers.exe`
6. Check **Flashboot Drivers**
7. Scroll down
8. Check **Xperia Z3 Compact Device Driver**
9. Click **Install**
10. Accept any warnings that appear

The device drivers are installed.

### Install Platform Tools

Download and install the Android Debug Bridge (ADB) as follows:

1. Download [ADB platform tools](https://adb.clockworkmod.com/)
2. Unzip into `C:\Program Files\platform-tools`
3. Open a [command prompt](https://conemu.github.io/)
4. Type: `cd C:\Program Files\platform-tools`
5. Type: `adb devices`
6. Authorize the connection on the phone.

The phone is listed and the ADB platform tools are installed.

### Unblock the Bootloader

Advanced users can use Flashtool to unlock the bootloader, which is not described herein.

Unblock the phone's bootloader as follows:

1. Follow along with [Sony's Guide](https://developer.sony.com/develop/open-devices/get-started/unlock-bootloader/how-to-unlock-bootloader/#bootloader_guide)
2. Complete Step 1: **Check if the bootloader can be unlocked on your device**
3. Skip Step 2: **installing devices drivers and platform tools**
4. Unplug the USB cable
5. Complete Step 3: **Connect to Fastboot**
6. Complete Step 4: **Enter unlock key**
7. Type: `fastboot -i 0x0fce oem unlock 0x{UNLOCK CODE}`

   - Replace `{UNLOCK CODE}` with the unlock code from Sony

The console shows:

```
...
OKAY [  1.544s]
finished. total time: 1.560s
```

The bootloader is unlocked.

### Reboot

After the bootloader is unlocked, reboot the phone as follows:

1. Type: `fastboot reboot`
2. Wait for the reboot cycle to complete

The phone is rebooted with an unlocked bootloader.

### TWRP

TWRP is a tool for writing custom software on mobile phones. Install TWRP as follows:

1. On the phone, visit https://twrp.me/sony/sonyxperiaz3compact.html
2. Install the Official TWRP App from the Play Store.
3. Download image into `C:\Program Files\platform-tools`:

   - [twrp_z3c_O_2018-10-27.img](https://releases.nailyk.fr/twrp/twrp_z3c_O_2018-10-27.img)
4. Power off phone
5. Unplug USB cable
6. Press and hold volume down
7. Plug in USB cable
8. Wait for blue indicator light in top left (may have to re-plug in)

   - Or run: `adb reboot bootloader`
9. Type: `fastboot flash FOTAKernel twrp_z3c_O_2018-05-09.img`

The output resembles:

```
target didn't report max-download-size
sending 'FOTAKernel' (10730 KB)...
OKAY [  0.345s]
writing 'FOTAKernel'...
OKAY [  0.722s]
finished. total time: 1.075s
```

TWRP recovery mode application is installed, to assist flashing ROM.

### ROM

A handful of ROMs exist. When choosing a ROM, also find the version of GApps that is suitable for the selected ROM. The Sony Xperia Z3 Compact uses a [Snapdragon 801 Processor](https://www.qualcomm.com/products/snapdragon/processors/801), which has a [32-bit architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualcomm_Snapdragon#Snapdragon_801).

Note: These instructions have only been successfully accomplished using CarbonROM and MindTheGapps.

#### CarbonROM 6.1

Download [CarbonROM](https://get.carbonrom.org/device-z3c.html) from:

- https://mirrorbits.carbonrom.org/z3c/CARBON-CR-6.1-NOCT-RELEASE-z3c-20200323-0711.zip

Download the ARM architecture version of [MindTheGapps](https://www.getdroidtips.com/mindthegapps-8-1-0/) from:

- http://downloads.codefi.re/jdcteam/javelinanddart/gapps

Alternatively, download the 32-bit ARM architecture version of [Open GApps](https://opengapps.org/) for Android version 8.1 from:

- https://opengapps.org/?api=8.1&variant=nano

The version of Open GApps must match the Android version of CarbonROM.

Skip to the **General ROM Installation** section.

#### LineageOS 15.1

Download [LineageOS](https://www.lineageos.org/) from ([forum post](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ru&u=http://lineage-os.ru/%3Fd%3Dsony-xperia-z3-compact)):

- https://rapidgator.net/file/1f8a3bdde3cd7ef6a19e9d87c314007b/lineage-15.1-20171103-UNOFFICIAL.zip.html

Skip to the **General ROM Installation** section.

#### OmniROM Oreo 8.1

Download [OmniROM Oreo](https://www.omnirom.org/) from either of the following sites ([forum post](https://forum.xda-developers.com/z3-compact/orig-development/oreo-unofficial-omnirom-t3696536/post74338146#post74338146)):

- https://releases.nailyk.fr/omni/z3c/omni-8.1.0-20180320-z3c-nailyk.zip
- https://drive.google.com/open?id=15COhmKqMBMiVeSLONSs38DaKymH2TWsv

Continue to the **General ROM Installation** section.

#### General ROM Installation

The ROM filename will differ, depending on the ROM that was downloaded, such as:

- CarbonROM: CARBON-CR-6.1-NOCT-WEEKLY-z3c-20180605-0603.zip
- OmniROM: omni-8.1.0-20180320-z3c-nailyk.zip
- LineageOS: lineage-15.1-20171103-UNOFFICIAL.zip

The steps to flash a given ROM are as follows:

1. Reboot the phone using: `fastboot reboot`
2. Start Xperia Companion
3. Click **Browse Xperia**
4. Copy both the ROM and the Gapps files into the phones download directory (e.g., `Computer\Xperia Z3 Compact\Internal storage\Download\`)
   [image: Xperia Download Folder]
5. Power off phone
6. Unplug phone
7. Press and hold the volume down button
8. Press and hold the power button
9. Wait for a slight vibration before releasing both buttons
10. Wait for recovery application to load
11. Swipe to allow modifications
12. Select **WIPE**
13. Select **Advanced**
14. Check the following:

    - **Dalvik / ART cache**
    - **System**
    - **Cache**
    - **Data**
15. Swipe to confirm wipe
16. Tap **Home** icon
17. Tap **Install**
18. Browse to and select the OS ROM file
19. Tap **Add more Zips**
20. Browse to and select the GApps file
21. Swipe to confirm Flash
22. Tap **Reboot System**
23. Wait for the boot to complete

Android and the GApps are installed using the specified ROM.

Answer (score 1):

A small note to [Dave Jarvis' answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/196723/44325):

I almost gave up, just getting adb/fastboot talking to the device.
Turned out to be a Windows 10 problem, because it refused without notice (?) to install drivers. The flashtool64 did complain however that it failed 2  of 3 in one of its windows, but I assumed (wrongly) that it was okay. I followed [this guide](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-do-i-disable-driver-signature-enforcement-win/a53ec7ca-bdd3-4f39-a3af-3bd92336d248) to disable driver signature enforcement:

> Please check if you have performed these steps to disable the driver signature enforcement in Windows 10 Technical Preview.
>
> 1. Press the **Win + C** and click on **PC settings.**
> 2. Switch over to the “**Update & recovery**” section.
> 3. Then click on the **Recovery option** on the left hand side.
> 4. Once selected, you will see an advanced startup section appear on the right hand side. You will need to click on the “**Restart now**” button.
> 5. Once your Computer has rebooted you will need to choose the **Troubleshoot** option.
> 6. Then head into **Advanced options**.
> 7. Then **Startup Settings**.
> 8. Since we are modifying boot time configuration settings, restart your computer once more.
> 9. Here you will be given a list of startup settings that you can change. The one we are looking for is “**Disable driver signature enforcement**”. To choose the setting, you will need to press **F7**.

Once this was done, the drivers were installed from guide links and with flashtool64, and then I got a message that the `adb` "was too old", so they were updated as well.

Note: If you follow [the guide](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/196723/264246), you *will* have new `adb` drivers. I assumed wrong (again) that my present ones would suffice.